Setup factory : add click to text
as you know, in the setup factory software, you cannot apply a click code to the text.
Now I need to solve this problem with a trick.
Now I add a text to the page, now I want a code to close the page when the mouse cursor moves to the location of the text and the user clicks.
sorry my English was bad
Setupfactory language is written with lua. If you know another way to do the click operation for the text, I would be grateful if you could help 
